# Very weird behaviour in Neo4j load CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

What I'm trying to import is a CSV file with phone calls, and represent it as phone numbers in nodes and each call as an arrow.
The file is separated by pipes.

I have tried a first version:

```
load csv from 'file:///com.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
with line
    merge (a:line {number:COALESCE(line[1],"" )})
return line
limit 5
```

and worked as expected, one node (outgoing number) is created for each row.

After that I could test what I've done with a simple

```
Match (a) return a
```

So I've tried the following step is creating the second node of the call (receiver)

```
load csv from 'file:///com.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
with line
    merge (a:line {number:COALESCE(line[1],"" )})
    merge (b:line {number:COALESCE(line[2],"" )})
return line
limit 5
```

After I run this code I receive no answer (I'm using the browser GUI at localhost:7474/broser) of this operation and if I try to perform any query on this server I get no result either.

So again if I run

```
match (a) return a
```

nothing happens.

The only way I've got to go back to life is stoping the server and starting it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you running?

Comment: Please, show us a sample of your CSV file.

Comment: the version is:

edition "community"
version "3.2.0"

Comment: this is a HEAD of the CSV file:

1||0000774|1994-03-18 00:00:00.000|12:10:12|182|MP018
2||0000774|1994-03-18 00:00:00.000|12:17:28|20|MP018
3||0000774|1994-03-18 00:00:00.000|12:18:33|34|MP018
4||0000774|1994-03-18 00:00:00.000|12:30:07|47|MP018
5||0000774|1994-04-08 00:00:00.000|10:19:05|38|MP019
6||0000774|1994-07-02 00:00:00.000|09:57:19|71|MP088
7||0000774|1994-07-07 00:00:00.000|09:28:59|62|MP088
8||0000774|1994-07-07 00:00:00.000|15:35:57|22|MP088
9||0000774|1994-07-07 00:00:00.000|15:36:34|27|MP088
10||0000774|1994-07-22 00:00:00.000|10:30:20|29|MP088

it's about 26 GB file

Comment: Thanks for the corrections... I'm not a good english speaker :P

Comment: I've tested it in neo4j-shell and worked ok

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that opening that big file twice will cause the problem because it is heavily based on the operational system how to handle big files.
Anyway, if you run it accidentally without the 'limit 5' clause then It can happen, since you are trying to load the 26GB in a single transaction.

Since LOAD CSV is for medium sized datasets, I recommend two solutions:
- Using the neo4j-import tool, or
- I would try to split up the file to smaller parts, and you should use periodic commit to prevent the out of memory situations and hangs, like this:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000
LOAD CSV FROM ...